# How can I change mimetypes setting in Artifactory Cloud

Tags: cloud, artifactory, mime-types

I'm using Jfrog Artifactory on Cloud, and I'm trying to change mimetypes.xml to serve html files as browsing instead of downloading.

I have read the article
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Configuration+Descriptors, about the mimetypes.xml file. But I don't have backend access to change the config file since it's hosted on the Cloud. How can I do it from Admin UI?

Answer (score -1):

You can submit a support ticket to the JFrog support team for this request and they will take care of it for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).